# PHP Upload image with md5 name

Tags: php, image-uploading

i need to upload images with `md5/uniqid` name.

PHP:

```
$filenamekey = md5(uniqid($_FILES["myfile"]["name"], true)); 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$filenamekey);
```

This move image into folder with `md5 name` but upload files without any image `extension/type`. how can I fix this?

Pic?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the file extension and add it to your `$filenamekey`.

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES["myfile"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filenamekey .= "." . $extension;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, You need to add the file extension in your filename, since you have converted your filename as md5 encoded, even it encoded the extension as well. In that case, you need to add the file extension.

```
$Filepath = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$filenamekey = md5(uniqid($Filepath, true));     
$Fileext = pathinfo($Filepath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filenamekey = $filenamekey.'.'.$Fileext;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$filenamekey = md5(uniqid($_FILES["myfile"]["name"], true));

// find the original extension and append it to the filename
$filenamekey .= "." . pathinfo($_FILES["myfile"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$filenamekey);
```